# Is there a word or phrase for language and culture combined?

Tags: terminology

> Mr. Doe is committed to learning and teaching language and culture.

Is there a term that embodies both language and culture? I want something concise, as I need to state it multiple times.

I considered "linguistics" as a possibility:

> Mr. Doe is committed to learning and teaching linguistics.

... but that doesn't really embody the customs and cultural side of the issue. I'm looking for a word that encompasses that aspect, as well as language.

Comment: _Teaching language and culture_ is pretty vague; it could be a course about language and culture, or it could be a language class with a lot of cultural material as well, or it might be a lot of different things. Maybe the best idea would be to get a better multiword description before looking for a single word.

Comment: Its a reference for someone looking to join the Peace Corps. Its a very involved reference and I need to address their desire and passion for cultural exchanges and language. Which this person does have in spades, I just don't know a great way to word it.

Comment: He's a _xenophile_, then. Most linguists are.

Comment: Hmm thats certainly helpful, not sure if it answers the question though at least as 'xenophile.' Do you think I could then say, "Mr. Doe is committed to learning and teaching xenophilia." That would translate to "learning and teaching an attraction to foreign things." So I don't think its quite right though I might call him a xenophile in another part of the reference

Comment: No, you don't teach it; it's an attitude that you have. The opposite of xenophobia. Most people are neutral or phobic about other cultures and languages (especially Americans); xenophiles are rare. I'd talk about him, rather than what he wants to do -- if he gets in, he'll do what he's told in any event. Concentrate on hard work and adaptability, plus enthusiasm for learning and teaching. He shouldn't be teaching English, though, unless he's had some good linguistic training; most native speakers are ignorant about real English grammar.

Comment: Nah, he's not ignorant about English by any stretch. He's taught it before including to foreigners and speaks, reads and writes I believe 11 languages, 5 fluently. Thanks for that advice though. Since it seems there is no one term for it if you make it an answer I will mark it accepted.

Comment: The sounds like a xenophile to me, then. As for your original question, it's interesting to note that even [anthropologists have trouble combining these two concepts](http://anthro.palomar.edu/intro/fields.htm).

Comment: @JohnLawler if you could leave Xenophile as an answer I'm happy to mark it so this can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Xenophile**

> Teaching language and culture is pretty vague; it could be a course about language and culture, or it could be a language class with a lot of cultural material as well, or it might be a lot of different things. Maybe the best idea would be to get a better multiword description before looking for a single word.
>
> He's a xenophile, then. Most linguists are.

Source: *John Lawler in comments*

> The sounds like a xenophile to me, then. As for your original question, it's interesting to note that [even anthropologists have trouble combining these two concepts.](http://anthro.palomar.edu/intro/fields.htm)

Source: *JR in comments*

Answer (score 2):

In a very important sense, "culture" does include language. Your point, however, is that you want to emphasize *both* the common social elements of the culture in question, as well as the language of choice. So it's almost as if you are looking for something that goes against your actual goal. I might suggest that you stop trying to mash these things together, and simply look for different ways of saying it each time it comes up. Also pay attention to the fact that some of the times you are mentioning this fellow's interests *might* be unnecessary or superfluous, and so you may be able to cut down the number of times you have to say it.

Answer (score 2):

The closest term you're going to find is "linguistic anthropology". Anthropology is, in essence, the study of culture (though, in and of itself, it covers art, language, and human behavior as a whole). Calling it "linguistic anthropology" specifies exactly what aspect of culture is being studied, in this case, specifically the relationship between language and culture. If that is the primary focus of study (as opposed to studying language as a whole and culture in a broader sense), linguistic anthropology is the correct term.

Unfortunately, though, that phrase will probably sound disgustingly snooty in most conversational contexts, and having such a "scientific" term may be off-putting, depending on the overall tone of any piece you are writing, and you may have to define the term for some audiences, making the use of the phrase as a "simpler" form completely null and void.